# rails 5 left_joins query with a few nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't understand how to write a good query. I tried something like a :

```
Users.where(id: params[:ids]).left_joins(:worker)
    .where(worker: { worker: { leader_id: nil } }).destroy_all
```

and

```
User.left_joins(:worker).where(worker: {Worker.left_joins(:crews).where(crews: { crews: {leader_id: nil}})})
```

but it's didn't work :( and I don't know what to do

Here are my associations:

User.rb

```
has_one :worker, dependent: :destroy
```

Worker.rb

```
has_many :crews, foreign_key: 'leader_id', dependent: :destroy
```

Crew.rb

```
  has_many :workers, through: :crew_workers
```

crews_schema:

```
create_table "crews", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.integer "leader_id"
end
```

Help me, please. Thanks!

Comment: Might help if you add any errors you received or what the expected behavior is?

Comment: I expected to destroy all users. who is not a leader_id.

How it works here:   def destroy
    if @user.worker&.crews&.any?
      render json: { message: 'This user has a crew with an assignment tied to it' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    else
      @user.destroy
      head :no_content
    end
  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Users.where(id: params[:ids]).left_joins(:worker)
# pluralised here:
     .where(workers: { leader_id: nil }).destroy_all
#                ^^^
```

The argument passed to `left_joins` reflects the association (i.e. `:worker`), though the `where` clause needs the **table name** (conventionally `workers` plural), which can cause queries such as this to break.

You've also got an extra hash wrapping that query.

And:

```
User.left_joins(worker: :crews)
    .where(workers: { crews: { leader_id: nil } })
```

For the latter, you can also nest the joins, e.g. `one: { two: { three: :four } }`, and pluralise the table names.

Let me know how you get on with that / if you have any questions.

Comment: Thx very much. need to read something like nested joins, how in your examples :) Thx very much. It's work perfect :)